# I have an error when I escaping string

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I am trying to write a string in my php code in my  panel.
This is given bellow

```
<?php
$str.="$('#layerList ul').prepend('<li data-refInd=\''+arr_ind+'\'><img src=\''tmp_card_imgs/\'+temp".$k.".name+'\' width='20px' /> Layer '+temp".$k.".zindex+':Image <span class=\'del_layer\' style=\'cursor:pointer;float:right;display:block;\'>X</span></li>');";
?>
```

but the error showing in console is given bellow

```
SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list
[Break On This Error]   

...data-refInd=\''+arr_ind+'\'><img src=\''tmp_card_imgs/\'+temp0.name+'\' width='2...
-----------------------------------------|
editor.php?id=129 (line 837, col 60)
```

What is the problem in my string escaping?

Answer (score 1):

Something is wrong here:

```
<img src=\''tmp_card_imgs/\'+temp0.name+'\' 
//        ^               ^
```

Should be

```
<img src=\'tmp_card_imgs/'+temp0.name+'\'
```

And you haven't escaped

```
width='20px'
```

Should be

```
width=\'20px\'
```

**Endresult:**

```
<?php
    $str.="$('#layerList ul').prepend('<li data-refInd=\''+arr_ind+'\'><img src=\'tmp_card_imgs/'+temp".$k.".name+'\' width=\'20px\' /> Layer '+temp".$k.".zindex+':Image <span class=\'del_layer\' style=\'cursor:pointer;float:right;display:block;\'>X</span></li>');";
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$str .= "$('#layerList ul').prepend('<li data-refInd=\"'+arr_ind+'\"><img src=\"tmp_card_imgs/'+temp".$k.".name+'\" width='20px' /> Layer '+temp".$k.".zindex+':Image <span class=\"del_layer\" style=\"cursor:pointer;float:right;display:block;\">X</span></li>');";
```